# Angular2 application freezes when clicks on routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am developing an Angular2 application for my internship and I have a real problem with one of my components.

This component is the main navigation menu of the application, and it's a **recursive tree view**, where each component instance contains a route to another component.

This component works well with few children, but in a real use case, around 300 children are recursively created. And when I click on an item of the menu to display another view, the application freezes. It seems to take a very long time to process the route, and I have timeouts.

The weird thing is that there is no problem with construction of the navigation menu itself, but it always freezes when I try to click on a route.

**Edit** : Here is some files on plunker -> https://plnkr.co/edit/VMC2SSuL4iaNJAjQxQ0c?p=info

Here is my recursive component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tran-location-zippy',
  template : `<ul *ngIf="location">
                <li class="li-item li-device-container" 
                    [class.active]="isRouteActive(['LocationVueComponent', {code : location.code}])">
                    <a class="goTo" 
                        [routerLink]="['LocationVueComponent', {code : location.code}]">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div (click)="toggle()">
                        <span *ngIf="!visible && !isEmpty()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                        <span *ngIf="visible && !isEmpty()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                        {{location.label}}
                    </div>
                </li>
                <span [hidden]="!visible">
                    <li *ngFor="#subLocation of location.children" 
                        class="li-container">
                        <tran-location-zippy
                            [location]="subLocation">
                        </tran-location-zippy>
                    </li>
                </span>
            </ul>
            `,
  styleUrls : ['src/style/zippy-menu.style.css'],
  directives: [
    ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
    LocationZippyComponent
  ]
})
export class LocationZippyComponent {

  @Input() location 

  visible : boolean

  constructor(private _router : Router) {
    this.visible = false
  }

  toggle() {
    this.visible = !this.visible
  }

  isEmpty() : boolean {
    return (this.location.hasOwnProperty('devices') || this.location.hasOwnProperty("children")) ? false : true
  }

  isRouteActive(route) : boolean {
    return this._router.isRouteActive(this._router.generate(route))
  }
};
```

Here is my data structure :

```
export interface Location{
  code : string
  label : string
  type? : LocationType
  parent? : Location
  children? : Location[]
  devices? : Device[] 
}
```

Here is my routes :

```
@RouteConfig([
{
    path: '/',
    name: 'DefaultVueComponent',
    component: DefaultVueComponent,
    useAsDefault : true
},
{
    path: '/location/:code',
    name: 'LocationVueComponent',
    component: LocationVueComponent
},
{
    path: '/devices/types/:label',
    name: 'DeviceTypeVueComponent',
    component: DeviceTypeVueComponent
},
{
    path: '/device/:code',
    name: 'DeviceVueComponent',
    component: DeviceVueComponent
},
{
    path: '/state/:label',
    name: 'GlobalStateVueComponent',
    component: GlobalStateVueComponent
}
])
```

Here is my view called by a click on a menu item, it's a basic component which call 2 children components. Children get informations from server based on **queries Input**.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tran-location-vue',
  template: `
    <p>
        <label for="refresh-button">
            {{ ((refreshing) ? 'STOP_AUTO_RESFRESH' : 'START_AUTO_RESFRESH') | translate }}
        </label>
        <button id="refresh-button" type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="toggleRefreshButton()">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>
        </button>
    </p>
    <tran-global-state [queries]="[query]" [timingRefreshing]="5000" [refreshing]="refreshing">
    </tran-global-state>
    <tran-alarms-states [queries]="[query]" [timingRefreshing]="5000" [refreshing]="refreshing">
    </tran-alarms-states>
`,
  providers: [
      CategoriesService
  ],
  directives: [
    GlobalStateComponent,
    AlarmsStatesComponent
  ],
  pipes: [
    TranslatePipe
  ]
})
export class LocationVueComponent implements OnInit {

  query : QueryString

  refreshing : boolean

  constructor(
    private _routeParams : RouteParams
    ) {
    this.refreshing = true
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let location = this._routeParams.get('code')
    this.query = {key: 'location', value: location}
  }

  toggleRefreshButton() {
      this.refreshing = !this.refreshing
  }
}
```

Comment: seems interesting, could you put it in plunker ? or at least add the component `LocationVueComponent` to your question ?

Comment: @Abdulrahman I added my `LocationVueComponent`, I can also add the two children components if you want

Comment: Yes, that would clarify things. I think problem is most likely to be in one of the `GlobalStateComponent,AlarmsStatesComponent,TranslatePipe,CategoriesService `. Or, maybe it keeps refreshing before you get a response. try increasing `[timingRefreshing]="5000"` to a huge number.

Comment: @Abdulrahman I put some needed files on plunker. I tried to increase `timingRefreshing` but nothing changes. I think `LocationZippyComponent` is the only component involved in my problem, because when I work with a small database or with a big one but with my navigation component disabled, everything worked fine. I really don't know how to debug my code

Comment: What if you remove `tran-global-state` and `tran-alarms-states` from `LocationVueComponent`, does the problem still happen? Also, if you look in the network tab, is there something not right ? like too many requests? or one request that takes too long ? Also, the plunker you provided isn't working, it's just code. But,I will try to reproduce your problem in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I changed the `changeDetection` strategy of my `LocationZippyComponent` component to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, and there is no freeze anymore. I guess it was a performance issue for Angular to detect change in 300 components simultaneously.